# Training neural network in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, neural-network, training-data

I have multiple .mat files. In each file I saved multiple features of an image (like intensity, hue etc). I want to train a neural network to categorize these images. I already have excel file containing the output  categories of each image.

Now question is that I have to load all the .mat files and fed it as input to neural network or I have to take only single file each time and its corresponding output category. Can anyone please clarify this? 
Also how can I give multiple .mat files containing multiple variables as input to a neural network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe is the best to load all .mat files which contain parameters you want to use for training of neural network and put all your input parameters into one variable, and than to use that variable as the input for neural network.